# Styling radio, allowing only 1 checked at a time

Tags: jquery, html

I know normally that assigning a name attribute to the radio inputs would only allow for one to be checked at a time, but I am restyling my inputs with jQuery and that will no longer work. I'm not efficient enough in jQuery yet to understand how to overcome this problem.

HTML

```
​<input type="radio" class="radio" name="one" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="one" />​​​​​​​
```

jQuery

```
$('.radio').each(function() {
    $(this).hide();

    var $image = $("<img class='checkbox' src='assets/images/layout/checkbox/unchecked.png' />").insertAfter(this);

    $image.click(function() {
        var $checkbox = $(this).prev('.radio');
        $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));

        if($checkbox.prop("checked")) {
            $image.attr("src", "assets/images/layout/checkbox/checked.png");
        } else {
            $image.attr("src", "assets/images/layout/checkbox/unchecked.png");
        }
    });
});
```

I figured that I need to alter my conditional statement to target whether or not the inputs with a specific name ('1' for the example) are checked, prior to changing the image. All of my attempts failed, unfortunately.

Comment: What are you using the name for that prevents using it as intended? jQuery can work with classes, other attributes, etc. do you really need to use name?

Comment: Try grouping them under a div

Comment: `1` isn't a valid value for `name` just like with `id`.

Comment: Sorry, I used the first thing that came to my mind. As the code sits, it allows for both of the styled inputs to be checked. I need it to only allow one, which I'm not sure how to do since I am using jQuery to stylize them. http://jsfiddle.net/ud7aM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each radio button, get it's `name` attribute.  Then, on the checkbox image click, get all the radio button elements that have that `name` and uncheck them, before applying the checked value to the one that was clicked.

[Example using your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud7aM/1/)

Comment: let's improve on this a bit, instead of changing the src of the image tag, change the class of the image tag, class checked will have the background image at the check mark position and class unchecked will have the unchecked bg position. so when you swap classes you are just shifting the background image.

Comment: Great, exactly what I needed. Question, though: Why is it that .next(img).prop('checked') is used? Wouldn't that be targeting the image with the checked property (which doesn't make sense)? I just want to understand, not just use it.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, and as @Huangism stated, there is much to be improved here.  I simply wanted to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Also, `.next('img').prop('checked', false)` gets the image after the radio button and sets the checked property to false, regardless of whether it is checked or not.  I figured, since you were setting the property when you click something, it would be wise to unset that property.